# Make a function that returns twenty two

Tags: javascript

[image]I am trying to Write a function that a given array consisting of N integers, return the minimum among all integers which are multiples of 11.

```
let arr = [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473]


function solution(A) {
    
   let mult = A.filter(x => x % 11 == 0 && x / 11 >=0 && x / 11 < 1000).map(x => x / 11)
   return mult
    
}    
solution(arr)
```

Comment: do you mean result as -22 ?

Comment: Thank you, Amit Verma, you are the nicest guy I have seen so far please if you look at the image it will give more precise of what I want thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Logic**

- From the list of input array, filter the array where the number is divisible by 11. Condition `number % 11 === 0`.
- This will give an array of numbers which are divisible by 11. Here it will be `[-22, 0, 473]`.
- To make pick the minimum value. Just sort the array and select the zeroth node of sorted array. Since the array of numbers divisible by 11 are already sorted the value for sorted array will be `[-22, 0, 473]` and the least value of them will be `-22`

```js
let arr = [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473]
function solution(list) {
    const divisibleArray = list.filter(x => x % 11 == 0); // This will return all numbers which are divisible by 11
    const sortedDivisibleArray = divisibleArray.sort((a, b) => a - b); // Sort the array. The minimum value will be zero th node of sorted array
    return sortedDivisibleArray.length > 0 ? sortedDivisibleArray[0] : null;
}
const result = solution(arr);
console.log(result);
```

**Single Line Solution**

```js
let arr = [-6, -91, 1011, -100, 84, -22, 0, 1, 473];
const solution = (list) => list.filter(x => x % 11 == 0).sort((a, b) => a - b)[0] || null;
const result = solution(arr);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

The question should be broken into two parts, then solved.
First, get all the numbers that are divisible by 11, then find the minimum of them.
So, something like:

```
function getSmallestDivisibleBy11(arr) {
    let divisibleBy11 = []
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
        if (arr[i] % 11 === 0){
            divisibleBy11.push(arr[i])
        }
    }
    let returnVal = Infinity;
    for (let i = 0; i < divisibleBy11.length; i++){
        if (divisibleBy11[i] < returnVal){
            returnVal = divisibleBy11[i]
        }
    }
    return returnVal
}
```

Comment: This solution uses 2 for loops and an array. This is not optimized solution.  This can be don in single loop without defining array.

Comment: Yes, it is not the most optimised of solutions. I was targeting understandability over optimization. I would NOT use this in production. But, for homework which from the looks of is not timed, IMO, this is neater. Just my 2 c

Answer (score 2):

```
function solution(arr){
    let value = arr[i]
    for (let i=0; i< arr.length;i++){
        if(arr[i]%11 == 0)
        {
            if(arr[i] < value)
            {
                value = arr[i]
            }
        }
    }
    return value
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can try this

```
function solution(A) {
            var minElement = 100001;
            arr.forEach(element => {
                let e = element % 11;
                if (e === 0 && e < minElement) {
                    minElement = element;                   
                }
            });
            console.log(minElement);
            return minElement;
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can first filter out multiples of 11 from the array and find the minimum among them.
You can use a for...of loop as given below

```
function solution(A) {
   let mult11s = A.filter(x => x % 11 == 0);
   let minMult11 = Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY;
   for(const mult11 of mult11s){
     minMult11 = Math.min(minMult11, mult11);
   }
   return minMult11;
    
}
```

or you can use reduce if you are comfortable with that.

```
function solution(A) {
    return A
        .filter(x => x % 11 == 0)
        .reduce((acc, curr) => Math.min(acc, curr), Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY);
}
```